# htaccess mod rewrite indentation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can someone please explain me how the mod rewrite engine works ? I just can't figure it out.

I have this code in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(johnny\.)?bravo.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bravo/
RewriteRule (.*) /bravo/$1
RewriteRule photo(/.*) bravo/photo/www/$1 [L]
```

I want this to work as follows:

johnny.bravo.com OR bravo.com should open index file in /bravo/ folder

johnny.bravo.com/photo OR bravo.com/photo should open index file in /bravo/photo/www/

This is currently working with this code BUT i want to get rid of the "bravo" string in the URL because when i open bravo.com/photo the URL gets rewrited to bravo.com/bravo/photo

Anyone know please how to do it ? I struggle everytime with this htaccess no matter how much tutorials i read :(